# JavaScript this keyword and object methods when passed as callback

Tags: javascript

I am building a counter example using an object just for practice and ran into a problem. I am trying to update an object property using a created method within my object method. I can get it to work when I declare the objects name and increment the property's value, but if I try to use the `this` keyword to represent the object my problem returns `NaN`. I think I know why without fully understanding. Can anyone help me to understand?

#### Example that works:

```js
let counter = {
  num: 0,
  increase(){
    counter.num++;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = counter.num;
  },
  decrease(){
    counter.num--;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = counter.num;
  },
  reset(){
    counter.num = 0;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = counter.num;
  }
}

let x = document.querySelectorAll("button");
x[0].addEventListener("click", counter.increase);
x[1].addEventListener("click", counter.decrease);
x[2].addEventListener("click", counter.reset);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="display">
    <h2>Counter</h2>
    <br>
    <span id="value">0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="increase">Increase</button>
    <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example that doesn't work:

```js
let counter = {
  num: 0,
  increase(){
    this.num++;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = this.num;
  },
  decrease(){
    this.num--;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = this.num;
  },
  reset(){
    this.num = 0;
    document.querySelector("#value").textContent = this.num;
  }
}

let x = document.querySelectorAll("button");
x[0].addEventListener("click", counter.increase);
x[1].addEventListener("click", counter.decrease);
x[2].addEventListener("click", counter.reset);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="display">
    <h2>Counter</h2>
    <br>
    <span id="value">0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="increase">Increase</button>
    <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shouldn't the `this` keyword point to the object (counter) making this example equivalent to the one that works?

Comment: “this” changes based on how the function is called. So “this” will be the element instead of the counter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @evolutionxbox is this because the this keyword is taking ownership of the button or method that it is attached to in this situation. I ask this because if I were to solely return this.num++;  and then call the function without attaching it to an event.  The increment will adhere.  Also, is there a way in which to used the this keyword still while attaching the method to an event?

Comment: The event listener is changing the value of “this” to be the element. You must manually bind the value of “this” before giving it to the event listener

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Awesome.  I figured that what the issue was, but really couldn't fully comprehend.  Thx so much for you help.  I will read the post that you recommended  to get a clearer understanding

Comment: you can also manually call the methods yourself when the callback runs: `addEventListener("click", () => counter.increase());` rather than getting the event listener to call them for you, this way, you're invoking `.increase()` and the other methods on the `counter` object, which will keep the `this` as `counter`

Comment: @NickParsons originally that was an idea that I entertained.  Is there any difference in calling the method manually than binding ?? Is it more or less efficient? Are there any side effect or using one over the other?

Comment: @Storm With `.bind()` you can set the `this` to be anything that you pass to `.bind()`,  it doesn't just have to be `counter`. It also allows you to partially apply arguments, but that isn't really relevant to what you're doing here. So `.bind()` is more flexible. Using the callback/method approach, the `this` is implicitly set based on the object that you invoke the method on (ie: it gets set to `counter` and you can't change that). In terms of efficiency, I don't see there being much of a difference. Worrying about efficiency for small things like this isn't usually worth the time anyway :P

Comment: @NickParsons your 100% correct.  Thx once again for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
x[0].addEventListener("click", counter.increase.bind(counter));
x[1].addEventListener("click", counter.decrease.bind(counter));
x[2].addEventListener("click", counter.reset.bind(counter));
```

you must bind with the object counter